# How to export German umlauts into excel file using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I´ve got the following issue for which I haven´t found a solution yet here.
I´m using Python 2.7 and I like to export Pandas Series to an excel file with umlauts ("ä", "ü", "ü")

e.g. for Python 2.7:

```
#Python 2.7###############

# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-

import pandas as pd
import csv
city = ['München', 'Nürnberg', 'Würzburg']
result = pd.Series(city)
result.to_csv(result.to_csv('Umlauts.csv', sep= ',' , encoding='iso-8859-15')
```

It only works for csv if I open it with Excel even though the result are in the same line and column

```
0,München
1,Nürnberg
2,Würzburg
```

**Question:**
What is the solution for exporting this Series frame into a Excel sheet like

```
A1 | A2
1  |  München
2  |  Nürnberg
3  |  Würzburg
```

And can I transfer this solution for creating files called 'München.xls'?

Thanks for helping!

Best

Comment: CSV is not "an Excel file". If you want to produce actual .xls files, use one of the many libraries that do that (e.g. openpyxl).

Answer (score 2):

As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31331449/624088), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48546542/624088) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213486/624088) you can use another engine when exporting to xls.
This works for me when the other solutions didn't:

1. Install [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/getting_started.html) `pip install XlsxWriter`
2. Import `import xlsxwriter`
3. Write using this engine instead of the default

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

where `df` is the DataFrame you want to export.

Answer (score 1):

Panads [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) doesn't support a dialect parameter. You will have to use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) module which supports excel dialect.

#### Disclaimer

Excel has issues with csv. Write the csv with UTF-8 encoding and prepend the utf8 bom `b"\0xEF\0xBB\0xBF"` in front of the file contents. Excel will read this file just fine.

#### HOWEVER

Excel **cannot save** csv files with utf8 encoding. Even when you open an utf8 csv, and press save without modifications, excel will re-encode it in `iso-8859-15`, with `?`-s inserted where a unicode character couldn't be encoded.

In other words: **Editing csv files with excel results in data-loss most of the time!**

Comment: \* Excel on OS X will probably still fail…

Comment: Your last statement seems overly harsh - if you can enter a character into Excel with the keyboard, it should be able to save it!

Comment: @Mark "Should"… :) I don't know whether or not Excel really does have issues with exporting "foreign" characters to CSV, but it certainly always had a very difficult relationship with processing UTF-8 in CSVs…

Comment: @MarkRansom as long as you don't have a russian keyboard :) I think I can find a letter on my hungarian keyboard as well, like capital `Ű`

Comment: @ALL: Actually, I like to avoid writing csv files. I would like to export the results in mac excel files directly using the xlrw package. As far as I know it should work using xlrw package, e.g. ´u"München`. But I can´t solve it. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should overwrite your `sys` settings and use `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel()`:

```
# Import modules
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
import pandas as pd

# Your code
city = ['München', 'Nürnberg', 'Würzburg']
result = pd.Series(city)

# Transform Series to DataFrame in order to use to_excel()
d = result.to_frame()

# Specify writer
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', options={'encoding':'utf-8'})

# Write the frame to excel
d.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')

# Save the file
writer.save()
```

This should work.

Comment: Oh so they have `to_excel`. Well, they are right that excel dialect of csv is pretty far from any csv :)